# How do you return an sf::RenderWindow?

Tags: c++, sfml

So I'm working on a tiny engine with my exploration into SFML. I currently am using a WindowManager class. Here is my code.

```
class WindowManager
{
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window;

public:
    void setWindow(int x, int y, std::string title)
    {
        window.create(sf::VideoMode(x, y, 32), title, sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    }

    sf::RenderWindow getWindow()
    {
        return window;
        //Error Here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the inheritance diagram for `sf::RenderWindow`:

[image: inheritance diagram]

You'll notice that it inherits from [`sf::NonCopyable`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/NonCopyable_8hpp_source.php). So you can't return a copy of it... because its copy constructor and assignment operator are private.

What you can instead do is either return an `sf::RenderWindow&`, or an `sf::RenderWindow*`, or a `std::shared_ptr<sf::RenderWindow>`, or ...

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you want to copy a window in your getter. I guessed you want to return a reference to your window:

```
class WindowManager {
// private: private is useless there.
    sf::RenderWindow window;

public:
    // Returning a reference. Note the '&' after the type.
    const sf::RenderWindow& getWindow() const {
        return window;
    }
};
```